# New field appears in Classic but not in Lightning

Tags: lightning-experience, salesforce-classic

So I'm new to Salesforce and am just playing around with objects. So after creating an object I edited it to create a new field. But I noticed that the new field appears in Classic but not in Lightning. What do I do?

Comment: It might be a cache issue, just log out and log in again, the issue will resolved

Comment: Hey, thank you! Yeah it did appear the next time I logged in. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you've converted your lightning record page to a dynamic form, the classic page layout no longer controls the layout you see in Lightning. You’ll need to update/add the field in the lightning app builder. The easiest way to get there is to click Edit Page from the gear menu when looking at a record detail page.